# Create a Cpmi User with Checkpoint API

Tags: api, checkpoint

I am trying to create a CPMI user from the Checkpoint API using postman.

I didn't find anything on the documentation for CPMI User and CPMI User groups but I could find something about generic-objects on forums. When I searched for generic-objects on the documentation, I still didn't find it.

I tried something like this with generic-object to create a user:

```
https://{{sms_ip}}/{{base_url}}/add-generic-object

{
    "name": "jdoe",
    "create": "com.checkpoint.objects.classes.dummy.CpmiUser",
    "authMethod": "INTERNAL_PASSWORD",
    "internalPassword": "jdoe1"
}
```

The user is created but when I try to log in on the Check Point portal, it doesn't work. It has authentication errors.

However, if I create the same username and password manually on the SMS, it works.

Any idea why on the API it's not working ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out from Checkmates that i need to hash the password before sending it.